# Array not passing correct value

Tags: php

i have following variable and need to use it in the array loop...

```
$jointa="'nike-score', 'pack-cupcake', 'shor-burgundy'";

foreach (array($jointa) as $id) {
    $yourSiteContent[] = array('permalink' => $id, 'updated' => $dated);
}
```

**but when i put the value direct in array loop its works fine....**

```
foreach (array('nike-score', 'pack-cupcake', 'shor-burgundy') as $id) {
    $yourSiteContent[] = array('permalink' => $id, 'updated' => $dated);
}
```

please check where i am doing mistake?

Comment: `s/ array($jointa) / explode(', ', $jointa) /` in your first snippet.

Comment: the thing is, `$jointa` is a string not an array. then you make it an array so its `array(0 => string)` and not the array you want

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$jointa = array('nike-score', 'pack-cupcake', 'shor-burgundy');

foreach ($jointa as $id) {
    $yourSiteContent[] = array('permalink' => $id, 'updated' => $dated);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$jointa = array('nike-score', 'pack-cupcake', 'shor-burgundy');


foreach ($jointa as $key => $value)
{
    echo($key . " = " . $value)
}
```